# How To Get Value of IR Search Bar Oracle APEX 18.2

Tags: report, oracle-apex, searchbar, oracle-apex-18.2

I'm trying to build a dynamic action on IR(Interactive Report) to capture the search value of the search bar. The search value should be pass to a hidden page item and I will then proceed with some code using this page item value. However, I have search over the net but did not found a way to get the value.

I have tried using `$("#apexir_SEARCH").val()` and `document.getElementById("my report search bar id which I get from inspect element").value`, but both of them did not work for me. Any Idea to get the value of the search bar before/after region refresh?

Answer (score 1):

**document.getElementById("myReport_search_field").value** is working, I was met other javascript error yesterday and hence no result is return due to that error

Thanks

Comment: `$("#myReport_search_field").val()` will also work.